# Finding WebElement by id Or by class?

Tags: java, html, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I'm using selenium Java to scrape different websites and i know for finding a specific WebElement there are different ways like by using Xpath or by using Class or by using Id.
Suppose if some website has html structure as shown below

```
<div id="column_left">
<div id="score_strength" class="box_analytics" style="margin-right:4px;">
    <div class="score">1<span class="score_title">%</span></div>
    <div class="score_title">strength</div>
</div>
<div id="score_sentiment" class="box_analytics">
    <div class="score">43:1</div>
    <div class="score_title">sentiment</div>
</div>
<div id="score_passion" class="box_analytics" style="margin-right:4px;">
    <div class="score">75<span class="score_title">%</span></div>
    <div class="score_title">passion</div>
</div>
<div id="score_reach" class="box_analytics">
    <div class="score">12<span class="score_title">%</span></div>
    <div class="score_title">reach</div>
</div>
```

Now , if i want to extract text from div with class name "score" and "score_title", i.e
1% strength, 43:1 sentiment, 75% passion and 12% reach which of the following option is best.

1. Using class="box_analytics" for Xpath and then looping through each WebElement:

   ```
    Lis<WebElement> elementList =  driver.findElements(By.xpath("//*[@class='box_analytics']"));
   ```
2. Using id="core_strength", id="score_sentiment", id="score_passion", id="score_reach"
   for each element

   `WebElement element1 = driver.findElements(By.xpath("//*[@id='score_strength']"));`

   `WebElement element2 = driver.findElements(By.xpath("//*[@id='score_passion']"));`

   `WebElement element3 = driver.findElements(By.xpath("//*[@id='score_reach']"));`

Answer (score 1):

Option 2 is better, it's clear and strait forward. it'll be easier to understand what is happing with code at later point of time.

Answer (score 1):

This depends on your HTML DOM.
case 1: If your DOM is static like mentioned in question and always will have 4 id's, you can identify element using id and extract text from it.
Case 2: If your DOM is dynamic (i.e. changes every time including number of id's), You need to prefer using class and get List from it using driver.findElements. Later you can iterate over via each WebElement and do getText().